# my javascript for a random generator

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in free code camp and I had the code working then a few days later it no longer works.

### Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var Quotation = new Array() Quotation[0] = "Damn it Jim, I am a Doctor Not a Miricle Worker!";
Quotation[1] = "Live long, and prosper.";
Quotation[2] = "Space… the final frontier.";
Quotation[3] = "Everyone remember where we parked.";
Quotation[4] = "A little suffering is good for the soul.";
Quotation[5] = "Conquest is easy. Control is not.";
Quotation[6] = "Beam me up, Scotty.";
Quotation[7] = "What does God need with a starship?";
Quotation[8] = "Nuclear wessels.";
Quotation[9] = "You will be assimilated.";

function getQuote("Quotation"); {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Quotation.length);
}
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#quote').text(quotes[getQuote()]);
});
```

I am knew to javascript and really don't know what I am doing.

Comment: Little tip: Make the code in a question as readable as possible, it will help you get answers. All code in 1 line (minified?) is not the best.

Comment: `function getQuote("Quotation"); {` What is this? I'm pretty sure you just want `function getQuote() {`

Comment: You say it doesn't work but you didn't explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It is supposed to return a random quote on an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are passing string **Quotation** into this function **getQuote("Quotation")** ? 
If you want, you can pass string "Quotation" to getQuote function like below.

 
Which will set **default value** to your parameter even if you are not pass anything to this function call. And obviously you should use this variable inside this function to get string "Quotation".

```
function getQuote(variable = "Quotation"){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to make a function using a string as a variable. So you should implement as

```js
function getQuote(){ 
  var quotation="Quotation";
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * quotation.length); 
}

or

function getQuote(quotation){ 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * quotation.length); 
}
```

and in the click method you should refer your array with its name (Quotation) instead of quotes.

```js
$('#btn').click(
  function() {
   $('#quote').text(Quotation[getQuote()]);
  }
);
```

Moreover make sure you have imported jQuery to your html code.